# I'm having an issue properly having the proper particle effect play when I hold the left mouse button down

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a third person shooter and as the title states I'm having an issue having the particle effect for the muzzle flash play when I hold the left mouse button down. Even though I'm using Input.GetButton the particle effect only seems to play whenever I let go of the mouse. The basic shooting works correctly and I've tried using another particle effect which only led to the same issue so I believe the problem is somewhere within the code. This code is mostly from Brackeys' tutorial on Shooting with Raycasts if that narrows down the issue. I'd also appreciate alternatives to implementing a muzzle flash effect with the particle system.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class FullAuto : MonoBehaviour
{
public int damage = 10;
public float range = 100f;
public float impactForce = 30f;
public float fireRate = 15f;

public int maxAmmo = 10;
public int currentAmmo;
public float reloadTime = 1f;
private bool isReloading = false;

public Camera fpsCam;
public ParticleSystem muzzleFlash;
public GameObject impactEffect;

private float nextTimeToFire = 0f;

public Text ammoCount;

public Animator animator;

void Start()
{
    currentAmmo = maxAmmo;
}

void OnEnable()
{
    isReloading = false;
    animator.SetBool("Reloading", false);
}

void Update()
{
    if (isReloading)
        return;

    if (currentAmmo <= 0 || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
    {
        StartCoroutine(Reload());
        return;
    }

    if (Input.GetButton("Fire1") && Time.time >= nextTimeToFire)
    {
        muzzleFlash.Play();
        nextTimeToFire = Time.time + 1f / fireRate;
        Shoot();
    }
    ammoCount.text = "Ammo:  " + currentAmmo.ToString();
}

IEnumerator Reload()
{
    isReloading = true;
    Debug.Log("Reloading...");

    animator.SetBool("Reloading", true);

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(reloadTime - .25f);
    animator.SetBool("Reloading", false);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(.25f);

    currentAmmo = maxAmmo;
    isReloading = false;
}

void Shoot()
{

    currentAmmo--;

    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(fpsCam.transform.position, fpsCam.transform.forward, out hit, range))
    {
        Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);

        Enemy enemy = hit.transform.GetComponent<Enemy>();
        if (enemy != null)
        {
            enemy.TakeDamage(damage);
        }

        if (hit.rigidbody != null)
        {
            hit.rigidbody.AddForce(-hit.normal * impactForce);
        }

        GameObject impactGO = Instantiate(impactEffect, hit.point, Quaternion.LookRotation(hit.normal));
        Destroy(impactGO, 2f);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure but afaik `Play` has only an effect if the particle system was stopped/paused before → It doesn't actually restart the particle effect.

> If the Particle System has been paused, then this resumes playing from the previous time.
> If the Particle System has stopped, then the system starts from time 0, and, if it is relevant, the startDelay is applied.

I think you could rather use [`Emit`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.Emit.html) and pass in how many particles to spawn each time

> Emit count particles immediately

```
public float particleAmount = 20;

void Update()
{
    if (isReloading)
        return;

    if (currentAmmo <= 0 || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
    {
        StartCoroutine(Reload());
        return;
    }

    if (Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
    {
        nextTimeToFire -= Time.deltaTime;

        if(nextTimeToFire <= 0)
        {
            muzzleFlash.Emit(particleAmount);
            nextTimeToFire = 1f / fireRate;
            Shoot();
        }
    }
    ammoCount.text = "Ammo:  " + currentAmmo.ToString();
}

IEnumerator Reload()
{
    isReloading = true;
    Debug.Log("Reloading...");

    animator.SetBool("Reloading", true);

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(reloadTime - .25f);
    animator.SetBool("Reloading", false);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(.25f);

    currentAmmo = maxAmmo;
    isReloading = false;
    nextTimeToFire = 0;
}
```